# Formatter not writing to file

Tags: java

I'm trying to write some strings to a file called "file.txt" but when I run the program, nothing is written.  If the file does not exist, it will create the file, but write nothing.

```
public class CreateTextFile 
{
    private Formatter output;

    public void openFile(String filename)
    {
        {
            try
            {
                output = new Formatter(filename);
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
            {
                System.err.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    public void addText()
    {
        Random randomnumber = new Random();
        int lines = 1 + randomnumber.nextInt(10);

        String text[] = new String[lines];

        output.format("%s","Hello");

        /*for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        {
            Textline tokens = new Textline("Hello",1);
            output.format("%s",tokens.toString());
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra block (the curly braces) outside the try-catch in your openFile method that isn't needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the `Formatter` once all formatting is complete

```
output.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The output from a `java.util.Formatter` is not written immediately, but is buffered in memory first. Note the documentation for the `file` argument to the constructor you used, at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.io.File)

> The file to use as the destination of this formatter. If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.

Since the `Formatter` class implements both the `Flushable` and `Closeable`, interfaces it has `flush()` and `close()` methods. To flush buffered data to disk, call `flush()` and the waiting data will be written immediately. Then, once you are finished using the `Formatter` call `close()` and the remaining buffered data will be written out.

So, for example, you could have code like this after formatting each bit of data:

```
output.format("%s","Hello");
output.flush();
```

Or, to make sure everything is written out even if there is an exception, use a *finally* block to call the `close()` method:

```
Formatter output = new Formatter("file.txt");
try {
    // your code
} finally {
    output.close();
}
```

If you're using Java 7.0 then because `Formatter` also implements `AutoCloseable` a *try-with-resources* block could be used instead of the *finally* block:

```
try (Formatter output = new Formatter("file.txt") {
    // your code
}
```

This automatically calls `close()` when the block completes.